# Leap Motion Java SDK, java.library.path

Tags: scala, leap-motion

I'm using LeapJava.jar to write a simple JDK program to interface with the Leap. I've roughly followed this article: [Developing for the Leap Motion controller in Scala](http://www.restlessprogrammer.com/2013/03/developing-for-leap-motion-controller.html) and in theory it's all very simple. However, when I try to run the program it fails with a `RuntimeException` when it tries to connect to the Leap device:

```
Native code library failed to load. 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no LeapJava in java.library.path
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
  at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
```

I've followed the steps in [the Leap documentation](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/Languages/Java/Guides/Setup_Java.html) but since I'm using Ubuntu (and [sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/)) there aren't clear instructions that relate directly to this situation. I've tried various different parameters for the java.library.path argument:

- pointing at the ./lib dir in the project (which contains LeapJava.jar)
- using the Leap SDK's lib directory
- absolute path to the Leap SDK's lib directory
- the x86 dir within the LeapSDK's lib directory
- symlinking the LeapJava.jar file into the x86 directory and using that

I get the same problem running it in IntelliJ (set up as described in the Leap docs linked above) or from the command line. e.g.

```
sbt -Djava.library.path=.:/<path to LeapSDK>/lib run
```

I've added the LeapJava.jar to the classpath in sbt (it's in the lib directory) and the project compiles fine.

Any advice (particularly as I'm on Linux, which is poorly documented) would be most welcome.

Comment: One thing to watch out for: if the native library is 32-bit, you'll need to use a 32-bit JVM, and if it's 64-bit, you'll need to use a 64-bit JVM. A 32-bit JVM cannot load a 64-bit native library and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the .dll files in the the project(your current working directory)  folder since it looks for the native libraries in that particular folder.

Comment: It worked for me. I copied all files from sdk/lib/x64 to the root folder of my netbeans project.

Answer (score 0):

From the Readme in the Leap Motion Linux package:

> Q. ...Sample.java compiles, but when
>   attempting to    run, I get an error about unable to load
>   libLeapJava.so
>
> A. Java seems to have trouble searching for native
>   libraries without some    guidance. Try:
>        LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. java -classpath .:LeapJava.jar Sample

which looks like it assumes the jar file and native libraries are in the same folder as your application.

Answer (score 0):

I got things rolling in eclipse on Ubuntu  by doing the following.

1)Select your project in the Package Explorer area and press a right click on it.

2) Select Build Path → Configure Build Path... option.

3) In the appearing window, select the Libraries tab.

4) Then, expand the JRE System library option and select the Native library location.

5) Click on the Edit button at the right panel

6) click external folder.

7) navigate to your download of the sdk .../LeapSDK/lib/x64

if you are on a 32 bit system use x86

You should now be able to use LeapJava.jar without error.